# How to I overlay a histogram over a bar chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bar-chart

I have a dichotomous factor variable that I want to create a bar chart with.

```
outcome <- as.factor(c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No",  "No",  "No",  "Yes", "Yes", "No",  "No",  "Yes", "No",  "No",  "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No",  "No",  "Yes", "No",  "No",  "Yes", "Yes", "No"))
```

And I have a continuous variable (min=0, max=1) that I want to create a histogram with

```
prediction  <-  c(.648,  .628,  .774, .292,  .264,  .598,  .720,  .876,  .520,  .676,  .736,  .244,  .326,  .594,   .492,  .168, .200,  .286,   .804, .086,   .382,  .878,  .450,.478)
```

I am trying to figure out how to overlay the two charts on the same plot. This is what I have so far:

```
df <- data.frame(outcome, prediction)     

ggplot(data=df) + 
       geom_bar(aes(outcome), alpha = .2, color = "red") +
       scale_y_continuous() + 
       geom_histogram(aes(prediction), alpha = .2, color = "blue", bins = 20)
```

[image]

It's close but the bar chart needs to be moved to the left. I want the bar "No" to go from 0 to .5 and "Yes" to go from .5 to 1.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What do you want to show with the bar chart and what with the histogram? Why you don't split the histograms by outcome?

Comment: It makes sense to do something like this with your histogram(s): http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-histogram-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: The x of your bar chart is given by the value of factors Yes and No (so 1 and 2). You can put the x values you want in the ses call, and set the labels separately

Answer (score 1):

This will move the bar charts to the left. You'll still need to fix the labels though. I'm not 100% if this is what you wanted but it's a start.

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(outcome), alpha = .2, color = "red", width = 1, position = position_nudge(x=-0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(prediction), alpha = .2, color = "blue", bins = 20)
```